# Contribution Widget

Tags: civicontribute, widget

I can't figure out why the [Widget](http://www.unitedwaymcca.org/hcshsbc-20th-anniversary-reunion) on my contribution page only shows "-- placeholder --" although about and button text are filled out...?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your server is not configured to execute php file using url https://www.unitedwaymcca.org/sites/unitedwaymcca.org/modules/civicrm//extern/widget.php?cpageId=40&widgetId=10&format=3

I can see 403 Forbidden nginx error in browser console. This URL is responsible to build the widget.

You may find more reasons for this error in servers access or error logs.